# iPhone Not Showing Notification Content in Banner

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, bug

This seems like a privacy setting, or some sort of notification setting, but I can't seem to find any option to reenable this functionality.

Current settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvBJT.jpg

Issue at hand:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpPe2.jpg

If it helps, I was on the iOS 10.2.1 beta before downgrading back to 10.2. And if it is due to some form of corruption from iOS 10.2.1b1 how should I go about fixing the issue? Should I do a full restore?

Comment: Can you try the iOS 10.3 beta?

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot of your current settings you are actually on the correct page, you just hadn't scrolled down far enough. If you go back to 'Settings > Notifications > Messages' and scroll down to below the "**Messages Options**" section the feature you want to enable to fix your problem is called "**Show Previews**".
Hope this helps! And if it does not fix the issue you're having could you post a new screenshot of what it shows below the "Messages Options" cutoff point in your original 'Settings' screenshot?

Comment: That fixed the iMessage display issue, but the other notifications are still blanked out. (Look at the first image in the second set of images if you don't know what I mean. IFTTT shows nothing).

Comment: I have taken a look and unfortunately there are no Notification Settings for the IFTTT app that can be controlled via the iOS Settings. (I even installed it on my iPhone to double-check.) I myself do not use IFTTT, but have you explored the settings within the app itself or your IFTTT account to see if something was turned off? Also, do you have a screenshot of what an IFTTT notification banner is supposed to look like?

Comment: Well, it's not just IFTTT. It's all applications. I just used IFTTT as an example because I can trigger notifications from cURL.